# Selenium WebDriver WebElement .findElement always return error (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The 'wait until element located' works, and I can get the container's text. But then when I try to get the title of products by looping thru the array of WebElements inside the container, the .findElement() always reject with error:

**The #product_container is dynamically generated**

```html
<div id="product_container">
  <div class="product"><div class="wrapper"><span class="product_title">Title 1</span></div></div>
  <div class="product"><div class="wrapper"><span class="product_title">Title 2</span></div></div>
  <div class="product"><div class="wrapper"><span class="product_title">Title 3</span></div></div>
  <div class="product"><div class="wrapper"><span class="product_title">Title 4</span></div></div>
</div>
```

```js
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  let container = By.css('#product_container');
  try {
    await driver.get('https://example.com/search/?q=mySearchText');
    
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(container), 10000); // <-- Success
    
    const result = await (await driver.findElement(container)).getText() // <-- Success
    console.log(result) // <-- Success
    
    const items = await (await driver.findElement(container)).findElements(By.css('.product')) // <-- Success

    items.forEach(async (item, i)=>{
      // Find the title of each product
      item
        .findElement(By.css('.product_title'))
        .then(()=>{
          console.log('success')
        })
        .catch(err=>{
          console.log('failed', err) // <-- Always rejected to here
        });
    })
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

**The error message**

> failed Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:56016
> at ClientRequest. (/./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:262:15)
> at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
> at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that it is actually a problem of JavaScript promise and async. It is because of the items.forEach do not wait until the promises resolved inside its async function. I ended up solving it by using **Promise.all()**, like so:

```js
await Promise
      .all(items.map(async (item)=>{
        let title = await (await item.findElement(By.css('.product_title'))).getText()
        return Promise.resolve(title)
      }))
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log('Array of title:', result)
      });
```